# What's best linux App to adjust the screen's color temperature

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screen

I am looking for desktop app in Linux System to change the screen color temperature.

I've tried searching on google but I couldn't find anything related information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

redshift will probably do what you are looking for:
[redshift on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/redshift)

While redshift normally operates in automatic mode, it is capable of accepting a user-defined color temperature:

`redshift -O <desired color temperature in K>`